# Trace() method doesnt work in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

When I put a trace("test"); at the entry point of my flashdevelop project and run it. The application runs fine but I do not see the trace in the output. Below is my code

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Anthony Gordon
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            trace("test");
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            var game:Game = new Game(stage);
            addChild(game);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the call to `removeEventListener` will fail if the event listener was never added (in the else of `Main`). Also, make sure (using a breakpoint) that init is being called in the first place. If it isn't, I have a suspicion the document class is not added to the stage. But I could be wrong!

Comment: @Cameron: no, sorry. that's wrong. look in the language reference. you'll also discover, there's no way to find out whether a handler is already registered to a dispatcher, thus such behaviour would really be a great flaw.

Comment: @back2dos: You're right! There's `hasEventListener`, but it only checks for the event type without the specific callback.

Answer (score 7):

If your trying to view the traces in flash develop you need to look under the logs tab, and click start tracking, the traces will then appear in the logs output not the output tab.

http://www.zedia.net/2010/log-trace-log-release-log/

Also allows you to see traces from flash apps running inside a browser :)

Comment: `look under the logs tab, and click start tracking` Works great... This took me days to figure out.

Comment: make sure your in 'debug' not 'release' mode too (dropdown on toolbar)

Comment: I've gone a couple of years without, until I saw your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, and it turned out that I was testing the project in Release mode instead of Debug. If not in Debug mode, it will not print traces. It's the drop-down just to the right of the Test Project button.

Answer (score 1):

get the [flash player content debugger](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html). to associate SWFs with the standalone debug player, you must launch it once.

Please note the debug player is somewhat slower. You need the 'standalone' player if you are running your flash apps in a popup window, or you need one or both of the plugins if you plan to test your flash apps in a web browser (one plugin is for IE, one plugin is for all other browsers)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with this, and didn't find a good answer. This was the top result on the search, so I'll drop some info here.

I had set up FlashDevelop 4.0.4 to work, had the right Flex SDK, had the debuggers. checked every setting, uninstalled, reinstalled, rebooted, and just about everything else you could imagine.

I wound up discovering that my application's entry point class was not actually named Main. It turns out, this was causing my traces to seem like they were failing, as the document class won't print traces unless it is named Main.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me one day - completely out of the blue for no reason.  I was able to solve the problem using Project > Properties > Compiler Options and then setting the "Omit Trace Functions" option from "true" to "false".

Screenshot:

[image: Click for a picture]

Answer (score 0):

Recently had this problem, hope I can help anyone here that had the same issues. I'm going to assume you're using the Flex SDK and are on Windows.

As others have said, make sure you're testing in **Debug** mode.

If you're like me and that didn't work, see if swf's default application is the flex's runtime. *flex_sdk_4.6\runtimes\player\11.1\win\FlashPlayerDebugger.exe*

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

update  Java Run Time to 1.6 or higher
It worked for me